# <figure> taking extra 4px in content height

Tags: css, html, figure

I'm trying to add an image inside the `figure` tag, but its leaving a small 4px space under the image, which becomes very obvious on adding a border to `figure`. I could not set width to  `figure` tag, since the width of the image is unknown while the html is rendered.

http://codepen.io/shahalpk/pen/cltAn

Comment: Not quite sure I understand but looking at your example, I added a border and there is no 4px space underneath the 300x300 image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make your image display block, like so:

```
figure img {

display: block;

}
```

Example using your code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dazFt